# How do I send a bunch of json objects in an ajax response with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, pdo

I'm playing with jQuery's $.ajax and I'm not sure how I should be doing the following:

Here's my javascript (right now its just embedded in the html page)

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'DBConnect.php',
    data: '',
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function(data) {

        console.dir(data);
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        dir(thrownError);
        dir(xhr);
        dir(ajaxOptions);
    }
});
```

Here is what DBConnect.php looks like:

```
$username = "root";
$pass = "pass";
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$dbname = "test";

//queries
$table = "events";
$fetchAll = "SELECT * FROM $table";

try {
    $DB = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $pass);
    //_WARNING uncommented when debugging
    $DB->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
    //$DB->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
    $query = $DB->query($fetchAll);
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    while($row = $query->fetch()) {
        echo json_encode($row);
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$DB = null;
```

Doing this I get a syntax error. I thought I could get away with returning every row as a json object, but clearly that doesn't work. I could just add all the row objects to one array and convert that to json, but I wanted to know if there was a better\more efficient way to do this.

Comment: This will just return the first row of your result...

Comment: Concat the rows first, then json_encode().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the while loop:

```
$temp = array();
while($row = $query->fetch()) {
    $temp[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($temp);
```

Try this, and let me know if that helps!

Comment: I figured I would have to do that. But is this an appropriate way to pass json data back to the browser? I guess I'm really asking if my general approach is flawed -should have made that clearer in my question.

Comment: Your original approach is indeed flawed. You cannot continue to echo results in a while loop. The output would not be a valid json object (it would be a string of concatenated json objects).